# Adding Two sets of data from 2 different queries together

Tags: sql, sum, addition

I have 2 queries which gather one half of the data i need and the other half from the other query,  the data i get needs to be added by the data in the other query.

First Query...

```
SELECT 
    RO_OFFICER,RO_ACTIVITY , COUNT(RO_ACTIVITY)*Value as [Value*NumofActivity]
FROM    
    RoleCall.dbo.ROSTER as ro inner join [RSWH].DBO.[RSWHT_Hours_Assigned_To_Markers_LookUp] AS MR on RO_ACTIVITY = MR.MARKER
WHERE 
    ro_officer = '41584 ' 
    AND RO_STATUS = 'INFO'
    AND  RO_SHIFT_START between DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
GROUP BY  
    RO_OFFICER,RO_ACTIVITY,Value
```

and the data returned is ...

```
  RO_OFFICER   RO_ACTIVITY   Value*NumofActivity
     41584      AVDAY           0
     41584      AVNIGHT         0
     41584      CALLIN          0
     41584      LATE            0
     41584      LEAVE           30
     41584      MSGLEFT         6
     41584      NOCONTACT       54
     41584      NOTAVAIL        30
     41584      OTHER           12
     41584      REFUSED         84
```

2nd query...

```
SELECT 
    RO_OFFICER ,(ISNULL(SUM(RO_SHIFT_LENGTH - RO_BREAK_LENGTH), 0.0)/60.0)as [NumOfHoursWorkedInTheLast12Weeks],RSWH.dbo.RSWHF_GetMarker(RO_OFFICER, DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS Markers
FROM 
    ROLECALL.DBO.ROSTER as ro inner join [RSWH].DBO.[RSWHT_Hours_Assigned_To_Markers_LookUp] AS MR on RO_ACTIVITY = MR.MARKER
WHERE 
    RO_SHIFT_START >= DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()) AND RO_SHIFT_START <= GETDATE()
    AND RO.RO_STATUS = 'INFO'
    AND RO_OFFICER = '41584'

GROUP BY 
    RO_OFFICER
```

which returns....

```
   RO_OFFICER   NumOfHoursWorkedInTheLast12Weeks         Markers
   41584        166.066666                           AVDAY(3), AVNIGHT(1), CALLIN(1), LATE(4), LEAVE(5), MSGLEFT(1), NOCONTACT(9), NOTAVAIL(5), OTHER(2),
```

I need to Sum the Value*NumofActivity column from the first query and then add numofhoursworkedinthelast12weeks from the second query.

So the Final Outcome should look something like this...

```
Ro_Officer    TotalHours 
   41584         382
```

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: I think that "Union" might be what you're looking for.  As long as the returned columns are the same, you can append the second set to the first set.

Comment: @durbnpoisn The issue is the columns aren't the same , there is more if one than the other

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? You may want to replace the join with a left or right join if appropriate but a join should work in any case.

```
Select a.RO_OFFICER, a.[Value*NumofActivity] + b.NumOfHoursWorkedInTheLast12Weeks [TotalHours]

from

(SELECT 
RO_OFFICER [RO_OFFICER],RO_ACTIVITY , COUNT(RO_ACTIVITY)*Value as [Value*NumofActivity]
FROM    
RoleCall.dbo.ROSTER as ro inner join [RSWH].DBO.[RSWHT_Hours_Assigned_To_Markers_LookUp] AS MR on RO_ACTIVITY = MR.MARKER
WHERE 
ro_officer = '41584 ' 
AND RO_STATUS = 'INFO'
AND  RO_SHIFT_START between DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
GROUP BY  
RO_OFFICER,RO_ACTIVITY,Value) a
JOIN
(SELECT 
RO_OFFICER [RO_OFFICER] ,(ISNULL(SUM(RO_SHIFT_LENGTH - RO_BREAK_LENGTH), 0.0)/60.0)as [NumOfHoursWorkedInTheLast12Weeks],RSWH.dbo.RSWHF_GetMarker(RO_OFFICER, DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) AS Markers
FROM 
ROLECALL.DBO.ROSTER as ro inner join [RSWH].DBO.[RSWHT_Hours_Assigned_To_Markers_LookUp] AS MR on RO_ACTIVITY = MR.MARKER
WHERE 
RO_SHIFT_START >= DATEADD(week, -12, GETDATE()) AND RO_SHIFT_START <= GETDATE()
AND RO.RO_STATUS = 'INFO'
AND RO_OFFICER = '41584'

GROUP BY 
RO_OFFICER) b on a.RO_OFFICER = b.RO_OFFICER
```

Comment: that didn't work, that just returned the same data as query two but a extra 10 times but it also didnt add the two columns correctly

Comment: @user3702989 Have you tried it with a Select distinct? Change the Join to INNER JOIN too and see if that helps?

Comment: Yeah i did give it a go and it didnt like it.

Comment: @user3702989 Try adding a Group by at the end of the query I done - 
Group By a.RO_OFFICER
and also if needs be change the select to:
Select a.RO_OFFICER, sum(a.[Value*NumofActivity]) + sum(b.NumOfHoursWorkedInTheLast12Weeks) [TotalHours]
If sum doesn't work try Min or Max.